# Stop words list for r

Tags: r, text-mining, stop-words

`stopwords` (of package `tm`) returns various kinds of stopwords with support for different languages. E.g.

```
stopwords()
```

returns 175 english stop words. I would like to know if there are some tools that provide more stop words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the package `stopwords`, You can specify the source with a longer list.

```
> install.packages("stopwords")
> library("stopwords")
> SW = stopwords("en", source = "stopwords-iso")

> length(SW)
1298
```